# is it possible to have an environment variable in the "env" line of a shell script?

Tags: shell

we have a requirement to have a script where the env is ruby (in a custom location) but setting the #!/usr/bin/env  , where script contains a variable e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ${NEWROOT}/location/of/ruby/bin/ruby
```

The calling script has set NEWROOT, and if I replace NEWROOT with the actual content e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env /home/user/location/of/ruby/bin/ruby
```

it works!

does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter substitution is performed by the shell, not by the kernel. The shebang line will remain unsubstituted even as the kernel invokes `env` with the argument.

Comment: sorry - this is all side work for me - i meant to say thanks. i realised i didn't understand expansion rules etc.